# domain and bounds propagation annotation in minizinc

Tags: minizinc

I wanted to know what exactly is domain and bounds propagation annotation. When should we select one over other?  I understand domain is set of value that a variable can take and bounds are lowest and highest value a variable can take.

Answer (score 1):

The MiniZinc language doesn't tell the solver what consistency level it has to use for its various constraints. For example Gecode will use value consistency by default for the `alldifferent` predicate. There are many different kinds of consistencies and it's up to the solver to determine a sensible default.

This default is not always correct for your purpose. This is why MiniZinc offers an option to [annotate a constraint](http://www.minizinc.org/doc-lib/doc-annotations-prop.html) to hint a solver to which consistency to use.

- `constraint alldifferent(x) ::bounds;` will propagate `alldifferent` with bounds consistency.
- `constraint alldifferent(x) ::domain;` will propagate `alldifferent` with domain consistency.

Note that these annotations might be ignored; for example when no domain consistent propagator is available in the solver. Some solvers, like MIP solvers, won't even propagate as such and will thus also not be influenced by these annotations.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth emphasising that the difference between bounds consistency and domain consistency is whether to spend extra time pruning non-solutions (at least in the case of CP solvers, the technology I have experience with); bounds will be faster for many constraints, but will leave more non-solutions in the domains of the constrained variables.

I'd like to augment Dekker's answer by adding that whether to use domain or bounds consistency depends a lot on your model and on the constraint in question (as well as the solver technology). In some cases, spending the extra effort enforcing a higher level of consistency might be entirely wasted, while in others it might pay off, either because your have few variables or they have small domains, or because pruning them tightly causes a lot of inference (that is, further removal of values not participating in a solution) on other variables.

The only way to know for sure is to experiment and see what works!